# Slow First Connection to other Server

Tags: discord.js, connection, windows-server-2019

So i got a little problem which i dotn know how to fix.

I have a freshly setuped Windows Server 2019 with nothing on it except Node.js, Visual Studio Code, Chrome and Postman

I wrote a Discord Bot with Discord.js
and try to connect to an API which also works just not the First time
Cause the First time i get an Timeout from the server with the api im calling.

But when i call the API first over Postman which takes about 2 seconds then the connection from the bot takes just a couple ms to connect.

After some time (2-5 hours) without any calls i have the same problem again.
The Bot loses connection to the API and cant call it again without the manual Help of Postman

and i dont know how to fix that issue.

Note: Other Bots can connect immediatly to the API Server with no initial connection delay

So my question is now. Is there any setting i missed to speed up the initial connection time or to keep up/save the connection to the api server?

Comment: I recommend you take a look at the [Discord.js guide](https://discordjs.guide/) and go through the steps to setting up a bot to see if you haven't done any of it.

Comment: Do you have any network issue ?